# Cypress fixtures best practice

Tags: typescript, import, automated-tests, cypress, fixtures

On the Cypress docs they recommend to use fixtures this way

`cy.fixture('logo.png').then((logo) => { // load data from logo.png })`
but I found it messy, and limiting because I can't reach this info outside a running test
so I'm using

```
import cred from "../fixtures/login_creds.json"
```

Is there a downside to using import?
of course I'm using it inside a cy method

```
cy.get(inputEmail).type(cred.email)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with importing a fixture.

It can be useful for data-driven tests.

```js
import sites from '../fixtures/sites.json'

sites.forEach(site => {

  it(`test ${site}`, () => {
    cy.visit(site)
    ...
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much every method of using fixtures is described here [Load Fixtures from Cypress Custom Commands](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/fixtures-in-custom-commands), including using `import` (last example)

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

import { users } from '../fixtures/data.json'

// note that Cypress._ is available outside of any test.
// the index k will be from 0 to users.length - 1
const k = Cypress._.random(users.length - 1)
expect(k, 'random user index').to.be.within(0, users.length - 1)
const testUser = users[k]
```

A lot of them use a "common variable" to store the fixture.

This works without any need to modify the test structure.

```js
// use a common variable to store the random user
let testUser

before(() => {
  cy.fixture('data.json').then(({ users }) => {
    // the index k will be from 0 to users.length - 1
    const k = Cypress._.random(users.length - 1)
    expect(k, 'random user index').to.be.within(0, users.length - 1)
    testUser = users[k]

    // we need to send the entire database object
    cy.request('POST', '/reset', {
      users: [testUser],
    })
  })
})

it('sets the random user from the fixture list', () => {
  cy.visit('/')
  const name = testUser.name
  cy.contains('#user', `${name.first} ${name.last}`)
})

it('has the test user', () => {
  expect(testUser).to.be.an('object')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**If someone comes by this and want to use Alias for fixtures.**

No there is no downside of importing the fixture yourself.
Please note that you are able to let cypress do all the heavy lifting.

You can create an alias of your fixture in a before hook to be accessible.

Please note as per the [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#this-context):

> If you store and access the fixture data using this test context
> object, make sure to use function () { ... } callbacks. Otherwise, the
> test engine will NOT have this pointing at the test context.

```
before(() => {
  cy.fixture('login_creds').as('getCreds')
})

it('Test Login Creds', function () {
  cy.get(inputEmail).type(this.getCreds.email)
})
```

Comment: you've not maximize the power of 'as' command and it can share the context.          
before(() => {   cy.fixture('login_creds').as('getCreds') })

it('Test Login Creds', function () {  cy.get("@getCreds").then((data) => {
  cy.get(inputEmail).type(data.email)  }) })

Comment: Depends on the situation, you can use both. it's easier and with less code

Comment: Unfortunately, aliases are **cleared between tests**.